# Can't obtain token consumption and costs on LangChain.js

Tags: javascript, langchain

I'm creating a project in Langchain and OpenAI and everythis is working correctly except when I try to trace the  token  usage  and costs on  every chain  run.

In python there is a method get_openai_callback()  from the Callback section from Langchain.py,  but I can't find the equivalent on the JS framework.

The Langchain chatbot isn giving me correct answers. It just gives me functions that dont exist in the JS  framework.

Does anyone have idea on how to trace token usage and generated costs on every chain run? Any help is welcome.

PD. I'm using ConversationalRetrievalQAChain with BufferMemory and Vector Search.

I tried  using this code that the langchain chatbot gives me

```
const { Chain } = require("langchain");

async function getChainRunCost(chainRunId) {
  const chain = new Chain();
  const callback = await chain.getOpenAICallback(chainRunId);
  const cost = callback.cost;
  return cost;
}

// Usage
const chainRunId = "your-chain-run-id";
const cost = await getChainRunCost(chainRunId);
console.log(cost);
```

But this function does not exist in the framework:
`const callback = await chain.getOpenAICallback(chainRunId);`

Is there a real way to return costs on every chain run?

Answer (score 6):

You can add the "callbacks" property with the "handleLLMEnd" callback function to get the total token usage on each model run.

Note: Setting the model to 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613' returning tokens only works using ChatOpenAI. It seems to be a bug or something. I'm using version 0.0.116.

```
import { ChatOpenAI } from 'langchain/chat_models/openai';

let totalCompletionTokens = 0;
let totalPromptTokens = 0;
let totalExecutionTokens = 0;

const llm = new ChatOpenAI({
    callbacks: [
      {
        handleLLMEnd: (output, runId, parentRunId?, tags?) => {
          const { completionTokens, promptTokens, totalTokens } = output.llmOutput?.tokenUsage;
          totalCompletionTokens += completionTokens ?? 0;
          totalPromptTokens += promptTokens ?? 0;
          totalExecutionTokens += totalTokens ?? 0;
        },
      },
    ],
    modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but my tokenUsage is an empty object... EDIT: Apparently it's an issue: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/2359

Answer (score -3):

You can add verbose: true to your chain or executor settings and it will log the tokens usage in the console.

Comment: This is downvoted because it doesn't result in printing token consumption.